# Quick Launch with dynamic width

Tags: javascript, quick-launch

Is there a possibility to assign the width of the quick launch dynamically based on content? In our case the text is sometimes too long to display the whole text.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,
you need JavaScript to adjust both the #sideNavBox `width` **and** the #contentBox `margin-left`

[image]