# Quick launch doesn't show all item's title when inside a library or list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, office-2016, left-navigation

This is what I get when I go on a page:

[image: Title is fully shown]

As you can see, the long titles are fully shown.

This is what I get when I go inside a library/list:

[image: Some titles are cropped]

As you can see, the titles of some elements are cropped.

Question: how to fix this? Is this a well known bug? Am I the only one to be annoyed by this behaviour?

I did Googled the question, and the closest likely answer comes with [Michael Mayr's question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203601/quick-launch-with-dynamic-width). But having a wider quick launch will not be very helpful - it will take too much space. I have full control on the site and I can use SharePoint Designer 2013.

I need help on this.

Comment: Use developer tool of your browser and see the HTML, if any CSS is affecting. Also compare HTML/CSS between the pages. You will get the difference.

Comment: Tried Asad Refai's solution. It's so difficult to see the elements in the browser (quick launch disappear when I try to wider the HTML). BUT Now I see this problem only happens in modern list/libraries, not classical lists/libraries. C'mon Microsoft! Can't you do better?!?